# I would want to translate Blender's UI to Finnish

Tags: interface

What would be the best way to translate Blender's UI to Finnish or any given language?

Answer (score 3):

There are, in fact, written instructions for this in the Blender Wiki under [*Translate Blender*](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Translate_Blender).

The process is generally called *localization*.  It relies on Blender's source code having been *internationalized*.  The later is done by replacing text strings with tokens called "message IDs".

To localize Blender your job is to produce a table that provides a translation for the English phrase represented by each message ID.  The Wiki describe how to go about doing this.

I strongly suggest contacting the Blender Foundation before you start, to find out if anyone else is already working on Finnish and to let them know you'd like to help.